# Why opencv failed to read a rmvb video?

Tags: video, opencv, ffmpeg, video-streaming

My opencv program success to read mp4 video files but failed to read some rmvb files and it gives the following error:

```
[rm @ 0x821f80] Invalid stream index 2 for index at pos 974024349
video has 300480frames
[rv40 @ 0xbac8a0] Internal error, picture buffer overflow
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Is this a bug of opencv?Anyone encounted similar problem?Thanks for any helps!

**EDIT：**
I found my FFMPEG indeed support rmvb using `ffmpeg -codecs | grep RealVideo`.But why this still fails?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, but **those messages are not from OpenCV**.

The OpenCV you have installed uses **FFmpeg** (libavformat, libavcodec) as a backend to handle video files. What this message is telling you is that you current FFmpeg doesn't support RMVB RV40. Upgrade FFmpeg and it's libraries.

An alternative approach is to compile OpenCV manually and set it to use GStreamer as a backend. [Someone](http://www.ozbotz.org/opencv-installation/) stated that the following packages need to installed to OpenCV's build can detect it during the CMake configuration. If your system supports `apt-get`:

```
sudo apt-get install libgstreamer0.10-0 libgstreamer0.10-dev gstreamer0.10-tools gstreamer0.10-plugins-base libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-dev gstreamer0.10-plugins-good gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg
```

Comment: But ffmpeg -codecs | grep RealVideo shows that my ffmpeg support all the rmvb formats and use ffmpeg to extract pics from rmvb video is successful.

Comment: in this case, upgrade opencv.